# Django管理サイトをユーザごとに分けたいが

Tags: python, django, social-framework

モデルをユーザごとにadminの画面を複数に分けようと思いました。

get_querysetを使って、ユーザを分割できるとのことで、
ユーザごとに管理をしたいモデル全てにユーザ（User）の外部キーをつけました。
このように↓

```
class Hoge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, verbose_name=u'ユーザ')
```

さらに、admin.pyでの設定はこのような感じです↓。

```
class HogeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(HogeAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        # 自分のIDでフィルターかける
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

また、添付画像のように、「スーパーユーザー権限」はなく、「スタッフ権限」のあるユーザで、
分離はできると思いました。

[image: スタッフ権限のあるユーザ]

しかし、このユーザを使ってadminのページにログインしようと思いましたが、
「変更のためのパーミッションがありませんでした。」となってしまいました。

[image: admin]

urls.pyにはもちろん

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

は記載しています。

もし、解決策があればよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: すみません。
adminでの見られるモデルの設定がされてませんでした。